# Replace group of similar text in string from nth position with one string else increment the value by +1

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I have a text file with following lines for example.

**Input**

```
DD0TRANSID000019021210504250003379433005533665506656000008587201902070168304000.0AK  0000L00000.00  N          01683016832019021220190212N0000.001683065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NAcknowledgment                                                                                                                                        
DD0TRANSID000019021210504250003379433005535567606656000008587201902085381804000.0FC  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NFirst Contact                                                                                                                                         
DD0TRANSID000019021210510360003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.0
CC0TRANSID000019021210510360003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.0
```

My requirement is
If the line begins with "D" then replace string starting from 14th position to 27th Position with D00000X (X being a number with left padding)

If I come across the same value of string between 14th and 27th Position, that I encountered before in the file, I should replace with D00000X, else with D00000X+1

**Output**

```
DD0TRANSID00001902121D000006003379433005533665506656000008587201902070168304000.0AK  0000L00000.00  N          01683016832019021220190212N0000.001683065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NAcknowledgment                                                                                                                                        
DD0TRANSID00001902121D000006003379433005535567606656000008587201902085381804000.0FC  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.053818065570067.000000.00000.0000000000000NFirst Contact                                                                                                                                         
DD0TRANSID00001902121D000007003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.0
CC0TRANSID000019021210510360003379433005535568006656000008587201902085381804000.0SR  0000L00000.00  N          53818538182019021220190212N0000.0
```

Comment: Are you sure the replacement happens at position 14? The output doesn't seem right - I see the change at position 21 (or 22 if 1-based).

Comment: Is'nt it the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559479/replace-text-in-lines-in-a-file-with-increments)

Comment: No, it isnt the same question. I need to repeat the replaced string, every time I encounter a duplicate string(string between 14-21 position) else keep incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are date/time stamps and increment in sequence then

```
a=($(grep -Po "(?<=^D.{13}).{13}" testfile | uniq))
for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=1)); do
    s=${a[$i]}
    sed -E -i "s/(D.{13})$s/\1${s:0:7}D$(printf '%06d' $((i+1)))/g" testfile
done
```

If a stamp repeats further down the file it gets a new counter increment. If you don't want that then the `uniq` needs to be `sort | uniq` which will apply the same counter to the same stamp throughout the file.

BTW, looks like you removed the 0 at position 28 in your example.